# Innosetup: Optionally delete a file with checkbox

Tags: checkbox, installation, customization

I've only used the wizard to make installers with Innosetup before and am struggling with how to learn to customize the installer.  Can anyone give me an example of adding a checkbox to the installer at the end to delete a file only if the checkbox is on?